# CSS Grid with children with set aspect ratio fit to parent

Tags: css, css-grid

I need a grid with fixed amount of columns and rows. Each column and row are filled in completely. Each cell consists of two parts - image with fixed aspect ratio (same for all cells) and caption with fixed height. I need grid to fit to parent (analogous how `background-size: contain` works). So far I came up with solution, which only fits grid to match width of parent.

Note: in this example parent of grid is whole screen, in real case it can be any size independent of screen size (so we cannot use `vw` and `vh` units).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  padding: 15px;
  gap: 15px;
}
.grid-child {
  background-color: red;
}
.fixed-ratio {
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
  background-color: orange;
}
.caption {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">1</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">2</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">3</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">4</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">5</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">6</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Including code in your question is good, but including a working snippet is much better. It enables us to run your code instantly to see what it does. You could turn this into a snippet in about two minutes.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Edit your question, and use the insert snippet button. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find one solution using a bit of Javascript and ugly usage of CSS calc function. I welcome another solutions which give same result but do not use JS. You can use this snippet to compare results of your own (please open snippet in full screen and resize window to see it in action).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    for (let entry of entries) {
      entry.target.style.setProperty('--parent-width', entry.contentRect.width + 'px');
      entry.target.style.setProperty('--parent-height', entry.contentRect.height + 'px');
    }
  }).observe(document.body);
});
```

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  html {
    --columns: 3;
    --rows: 2;
    --ratio: 4 / 3;
    --gap: 15px;
    --caption-height: 20px;
  }
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .grid {
    background-color: red;
    padding: calc(var(--gap) / 2);
    width: calc(
      min(
        var(--parent-width),
        (((var(--parent-height) - var(--gap)) / var(--rows) - var(--caption-height) - var(--gap)) * (var(--ratio)) + var(--gap)) * var(--columns) + var(--gap)
      )
    );
    height: calc(
      min(
        var(--parent-height),
        (((var(--parent-width) - var(--gap)) / var(--columns) - var(--gap)) / (var(--ratio)) + var(--caption-height) + var(--gap)) * var(--rows) + var(--gap)
      )
    );
    margin: auto;
  }
  .grid-child {
    padding: calc(var(--gap) / 2);
    width: calc(100% / var(--columns));
    height: calc(100% / var(--rows));
    float: left;
  }
  .fixed-ratio {
    background-color: orange;
    height: calc(100% - var(--caption-height));
  }
  .caption {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: var(--caption-height);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">1</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">2</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">3</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">4</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">5</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">6</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I completely misunderstand what you are wanting to achieve simply adding **height 100%** to `.grid` will make the grid fill the screen.

Reszing the screen will allow the content of the cell (image) to scale to the width of the parent while maintaining aspect ratio.

**NOTE**

The grid child image cannot fill the height of the cell while maintaining an aspect ratio of 4/3 unless the width of the container/screen is also an aspect ratio of 4/3.

The grid child text cannot fill the cell because it has a fixed height.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);  
  gap: 15px;
  height:100%;
}
.grid-child {
  background-color: red;
}
.fixed-ratio {
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
  background-color: orange;
}
.caption {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">1</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">2</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">3</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">4</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">5</div></div>
  <div class="grid-child"><div class="fixed-ratio"></div><div class="caption">6</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet in your answer is not working - result is the same as with mine, there scrollbar appears and grid's height is bigger than parents'.

Comment: Thats just because padding isn't part of the grid calculation. The padding would need adding to a container instead. I've removed from mine to demonstrate.

Comment: Still not working as required.

Comment: @Somnium Then I am not clear what required is? What do you want to achieve exactly? You said "I need grid to fit to parent". This answer does that. You need to modify your answer to be clearer what end result you want to achieve.

Comment: Maybe it is just not working for me. I am using Edge. For me it not fitting parent, but overflowing it with scroll. Edit: also tried in Chrome, looks the same. Please check my second answer to see how it should look like.

Comment: So what I think you are saying is you want it to be 100% height of parent ONLY if the height is greater than parent AND you want the body of the site to be 100% of the viewport?

Comment: Body is set to 100% just for easier testing. What I explicitly said in the question, that size of grid should work like css `background-size: contain` works (so grid width or height is 100%, depending which fits entirely)